# Python parallel reading lines in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, file, concurrency

Currently I have a function that just prints a content of a file's line to console:

```py
def readline(linez: bytes):
    print(linez)
```

And a code, that should do that in parallel:

```py
with open("large.log", 'rb') as file:
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for line in file:
            executor.submit(readline, line)
        executor.shutdown(wait=True)
```

That "large.log" file is 3.0GB size.
My problem is that I need to read a large file as fast as possible, since there will be much more files than just this one (more than 10, and each is >= 3.0GB). There is **NO** problem in reading lot of files concurrently, since I can use `ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=500_000)` and it will work fine, since these `max_workers` are virtual threads and not physical ones.

But how can I achieve that "virtual threading" in a reading file's lines task?

Python documentation also confirms that this `ProcessPoolExecutor` is directly related to physical threads, so I cannot spin 500_000 of them.

> Changed in version 3.8: Default value of max_workers is changed to min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4). This default value preserves at least 5 workers for I/O bound tasks. It utilizes at most 32 CPU cores for CPU bound tasks which release the GIL. And it avoids using very large resources implicitly on many-core machines.

All above mentioned factors tend me to think, that it is not possible to read file's lines in a separate threads faster, than it would be done in one single thread, i.e **reading one file in a single thread** is always faster than **reading file's lines in separate threads**.

Comment: from your text, it looks like you are treating "ProcessPoolExecutor" and "ThreadPoolExecutor" as if they where the same thing. They are fundamentally different (and both will use O.S. level resources, so even if you have some virtual-threading library installed, those classes won't use them)

Comment: Maybe, this is a task suited for use with asyncio rather than ThreadPoolExecutor - and depending on the processing you need each line, use a custom PoolExecutor to perform it.

Comment: Side-note: please don't use code font for things that really aren't code, such as "virtual threading". It's really distracting, and there are plenty of other options available, such as italics or bold for highlighting, or just putting something in quotes to indicate a particular term. For example, I'd write: But how can I achieve that "virtual threading" in a reading file's lines task? That's much less jarring IMO.

Comment: Having discrete threads where each one handles one file is a reasonable strategy. Trying to have multiple threads reading the same file and somehow interleaving the content makes no sense whatsoever. To do that in a robust manner would degrade the performance rather than enhance it

Comment: @jsbueno will try that async await approach and report back

Comment: @CtrlZ how would it downgrade a performance, when each virtual thread will read only one file line at a time? File itself is static and will not grow/shrink, so I cannot agree with that :(

Comment: @armaka Is the file descriptor returned from *open()* thread safe? It's a moot point anyway. Your strategy is flawed. One file per thread will give you optimum throughput

Comment: Since you have 10 files, why not parallelize *that* (e.g., one process per file)? Trying to read each line separately will almost certainly be slower due to concurrency overhead, and mess with CPU and OS caches. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython

Comment: @CtrlZ it should be thread safe as I first read a line, outside the new thread, and only then pass it into that new thread, so I can only hope that inside `open()` that file descriptor knows the start and the end of that line :) Okay, I got you about "processing file lines in a different threads" - bad idea, but still worth a bit myself research

Comment: @BoppreH thanks, found some video about GIL from the link

Comment: @jsbueno

`async def main():
    async with aiofiles.open('large.log', mode='rb') as f:
        async for line in f:
            print(line)
asyncio.run(main())
`
does it muuuuch longer, than reading a whole file within a single thread...

Comment: no - read the file synchronously, possibly in ~tens of MB increments - and submit each line as an async task. you will need some custom logic across the block boundaries so each worker gets whole lines.

Comment: @jsbueno I cannot read in steps of larger than exactly one line, which has no defined size and only has a "\n" separator. I still need to process each line. Yes, thanks, I have tried another approach:
`async def main():
    with open('largefile.txt', mode='rb') as f:
        tasks = []
        for ff in f:
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(readline2(ff)))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def readline2(linez):
    print(linez)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

asyncio.run(main())`
 however, I run out of memory SIGKILL 9 this time :(

Comment: yes. any apprach trying to simplify this as a small file will fail - this will not only try to keep all the file in memory, but also create a task object for each line in the file.

Reading the file synchronously can still work, but add some code to control how many tasks are created at each time. (~10.000 should be ok)

Reading large blocks, and getting some logic so that each block is passed to workers in line boundaries could take up to 20-30 LoC to do that right, but it will do the job - and if this is a task that have to be repeated, it can be calibrated for the optimal block size.

Comment: @jsbueno I tend to think now, that only `ThreadPoolExecutor` will do the trick, at least it works a bit faster than sync reading a large file. Since that pool can reuse threads, whether `asyncio` will simply consume available resources to perform concurrency and once it hit the limit it cannot do anything with it.

Comment: @jsbueno I have just tried it, and was reading 6 files, 3 of them are around 300KB and 3 of them are around 3GB, then storing some of the data into Postgres. Total time was 24minutes (my PC is 8cpu, 16GB). But asyncio has exited with SIGKILL 9 under same conditions. And morover, ThreadPoolExecuter seems not be bothered by amount and sizes of files

Comment: Read in one thread, pass the lines to other threads

Comment: @pippo1980 tried that as well, you can run to SIGKILL 9 problem, since once you spin up so many virtual threads you will run out of memory

Comment: @armaka Can you define "virtual thread"? How does that differ from a regular thread? Also, ThreadPoolExecutor has no knowledge of what its threads are doing - let alone have any knowledge of the size of files that are being processed. Can you tell us what you do with the lines from the files once you've acquired them? That may help us to offer a design pattern

Comment: @CtrlZ thank you for the feedback, yes sure, by "virtual threads" I mean cheap concurrently running Python functions on a single/or multiple cores. It is the same "virtual threads" concept as in Golang's `go func(){...}()` or in Java 21 `Thread.ofVirtual()`. Now, "what you do with the lines" -> I have a large log files, which I parse line by line, while parsing I extract only specific data and put it into an object (also each log record contain SessionID). Then I query a database (Postgres, but can by any other relational db) to check whether SessionID already there, and if not - add object.

Comment: @CtrlZ one of the caveats of that Python program is that there will be more than 10 log files, each more than 3GB, and the caveat is that if Postgres or machine fails, for some reason, there should be a way to restore the whole database as it was. Log files delivery is done via `rsync` from other nodes, so no problems here. But problem instead arise, when I should restore a database from a beginning and there are 15 files 3GB each, it could take too much time. It is worth to mention that unfortunately the machine (only one) is restricted to have 16CPU and 32GB only, not more

Comment: @armaka Simple solution... Don't use autocommit - i.e., only commit to the database once all files have been processed successfully. This is traditional transactional practice. However, it is possible that you'll hit memory constraints but that's the way it is if you might need to recover after some kind of system failure. There are more complex techniques that you could employ but they'll need special coding considerations like adding timestamps to the rows you insert into the database. If anything goes wrong you could devise a recovery process that removes rows created after a certain time

Comment: @CtrlZ thanks! Actually already doing it, I'm only concerned about that "restore process" will take too much time, that's why am I trying to read all files as fast as possible, and that's the where "parallel file lines parse" idea is originated from. What regards a database read/write timeouts then from Postgres docs it says that "30_000 writes per second" and "1_000_000 reads per second", which is very enough for me under any circumstances, so I can do writings to the database in batches, let's say "30_000 records --> commit etc".

Comment: @CtrlZ my only concern is that Python should read all files simultaneously and, in ideal case, all log file lines simultaneously as well (there will not be conflicts, as this is handled on log file parsing) without hitting any memory limit (so I assume there is some kind of  pool, that occupies and releases "virtual threads"). But yeah only in such case it is possible to perform super fast recover, as I initially desired

Comment: have you tried such an approach that you process each file using `futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()`, without specifying `max_workers` so not to run out of memory, and then you process each individual file using `asyncio.run(<func1()>)`. Now, inside "<func1()>", first create an array `tasks = []`, then you loop over all lines in a file and inside that loop just add a function "func2" that processes each line into `tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(<func2>))`. Outside the loop call `await asyncio.wait(tasks)`. And that should be it.

Comment: @ojacomarket could provide an example of that by posting an answer maybe?